# How to select oldest date from MySQL

Tags: mysql

Is there a specific way to select the oldest (or two oldest) dates from a column in MySQL?

I imagine I would use the ordered by criterion.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You can order by the date field in your database. For oldest:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition ORDER BY dateField ASC LIMIT 1
```

For two oldest:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE condition ORDER BY dateField ASC LIMIT 2
```

etc, etc, ...

Answer (score 32):

Single oldest is easy:

```
SELECT MIN(datefield) FROM yourtable
```

Oldest `n` values requires a LIMIT query:

```
SELECT datefield FROM yourtable ORDER By datefield ASC LIMIT n
```

Comment: Since OP want the oldest date, wouldn't he order it ascending instead of descending?

Comment: I know this is old but I was hung up on this question and it took me a minute to get through it. The answer is: No. The reason: He wants the "oldest" date and when you sort ASC the dates get ordered from lowest or oldest, to newest or largest. Then n posts are just pulled from the top of that data set. DEC would revers the data set, putting the newest (largest value) date on top of the set with the oldest at the bottom.

Comment: Didn't realize there was a MIN and MAX selector for dates. Absolutely brilliant!

Answer (score 1):

```
select MyDate from MyTable order by MyDate asc limit 2
```

Answer (score 1):

if the column type is date or timedate

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE 1 ORDER BY datecolumn ASC LIMIT 2
```

if the column type is text or varchar

```
SELECT *,DATE(STR_TO_DATE(datecolumn , '%H:%i %d-%m-%Y' )) AS columnname  FROM tablename WHERE 1 ORDER BY columnname ASC LIMIT 2
```

You can choose your date format from [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) .