# MySQL custom select order

Tags: mysql, select

I'm having problems with a custom order in a `MySQL` query. Any help would be appreciated.

So I have a table with the following data set:

```
id  SCADA  Date        Hour     Minute    Second   PlantNo  Key  Value 
 1   2924  2014-01-02  00:00:12 00:00:00  00:00:32    25    1300     0
 2   2924  2014-01-02  00:00:15 00:00:41  00:00:33     7    1300   500
 3   2924  2014-01-02  00:00:16 00:00:03  00:00:12    25    1300   500
 4   2924  2014-01-02  00:00:21 00:00:53  00:00:05    25    1300  1000
 5   2924  2014-01-02  00:00:21 00:00:53  00:00:05    26    1300  2060
 6   2924  2014-01-02  00:00:21 00:00:53  00:00:09     7    1300  1000
 7   2924  2014-01-03  00:00:07 00:00:42  00:00:06    25    1300  2060
 8   2924  2014-01-03  00:00:07 00:00:42  00:00:07     7    1300  2060
 9   2924  2014-01-03  00:00:12 00:00:00  00:00:03     5    1300    20
10   2924  2014-01-03  00:00:12 00:00:00  00:00:07     5    2501    18
11   2924  2014-01-04  00:00:11 00:00:52  00:00:56    16    1031     0
12   2924  2014-01-04  00:00:12 00:00:00  00:00:07     5    2501   8.5
13   2924  2014-01-04  00:00:13 00:00:51  00:00:05     4    1030     0
14   2924  2014-01-04  00:00:18 00:00:23  00:00:11     4    1030     1
15   2924  2014-01-06  00:00:16 00:00:08  00:00:36    26    1300  1500
16   2924  2014-01-07  00:00:17 00:00:11  00:00:00     5    1300    50
17   2924  2014-01-07  00:00:19 00:00:31  00:00:38     5    1030     0
18   2924  2014-01-07  00:00:21 00:00:00  00:00:53     5    1300   200
19   2924  2014-01-07  00:00:21 00:00:59  00:00:17     5    1300   500
20   2924  2014-01-08  00:00:08 00:00:28  00:00:53     5    1300  1000
21   2924  2014-01-08  00:00:08 00:00:56  00:00:33    26    1300   500
22   2924  2014-01-08  00:00:11 00:00:41  00:00:06    26    1300  1000
23   2924  2014-01-08  00:00:11 00:00:41  00:00:41     5    1300  1500
```

I need to SELECT only the last Value from each Key and each PlantNo. The last means the oldest date and time.

This is my code so far:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT SCADA, PlantNo, tblpartemp.Date, MAKETIME(tblpartemp.Hour,tblpartemp.Minute,tblpartemp.Second) AS Time, tblpartemp.Key, tblparameter.description, tblpartemp.Value
    FROM tblpartemp
    LEFT JOIN tblparameter ON tblpartemp.Key = tblparameter.id
    ORDER BY Date, Time DESC
) AS T1
GROUP BY T1.Key
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for code help, not for getting people to write code for you. Show us what you've done so far, what's wrong with it, and we can help correct it.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to put my code! I have edited my question

Comment: While it's not a solution, you could write a subquery based off of [this idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8125996/how-to-select-oldest-date-from-mysql), so select each unique key, and then find the oldest record of each.

Comment: But my primary Key is an auto-increment 'id'.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood what you were trying to achieve.

Comment: add the table and data to http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Why are you storing dates and times in this daft fashion? (Hm, perhaps I shouldn't ask) - and don't call a column 'key'. It confuses people

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query to achieve the result.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM plants ORDER BY Date DESC,Time DESC) AS t GROUP BY Plant
```

I assumed the table name as 'plants' and there were no other fields in the table.

Edited

Comment: Thank you, but it's not working like I need. Please see the image I have uploaded. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer. If this time it does not work, then I'm afraid, I didn't understand your problem, or your desired output is not in sync with your description.

Comment: Note that this solution works only by virtue of undocumented behaviour on the part of MySQL. But, that said, it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've sorted out the flaws of your design, consider the following:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

 CREATE TABLE my_table
 (id  INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,SCADA  INT NOT NULL
 ,Date  DATETIME NOT NULL
 ,PlantNo  INT NOT NULL
 ,my_key  INT NOT NULL
 ,my_value  INT NOT NULL
 );

 INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
 (1   ,2924  ,'2014-01-02 12:00:32'    ,25    ,1300 ,    0),
 (2   ,2924  ,'2014-01-02 15:41:33'    , 7    ,1300 ,  500),
 (3   ,2924  ,'2014-01-02 16:03:12'    ,25    ,1300 ,  500),
 (4   ,2924  ,'2014-01-02 21:53:05'    ,25    ,1300 , 1000),
 (5   ,2924  ,'2014-01-02 21:53:05'    ,26    ,1300 , 2060),
 (6   ,2924  ,'2014-01-02 21:53:09'    , 7    ,1300 , 1000),
 (7   ,2924  ,'2014-01-03 07:42:06'    ,25    ,1300 , 2060),
 (8   ,2924  ,'2014-01-03 07:42:07'    , 7    ,1300 , 2060),
 (9   ,2924  ,'2014-01-03 12:00:03'    , 5    ,1300 ,   20),
 (10   ,2924  ,'2014-01-03 12:00:07'    , 5    ,2501 ,   18),
 (11   ,2924  ,'2014-01-04 11:52:56'    ,16    ,1031 ,    0),
 (12   ,2924  ,'2014-01-04 12:00:07'    , 5    ,2501 ,  8.5),
 (13   ,2924  ,'2014-01-04 13:51:05'    , 4    ,1030 ,    0),
 (14   ,2924  ,'2014-01-04 18:23:11'    , 4    ,1030 ,    1),
 (15   ,2924  ,'2014-01-06 16:08:36'    ,26    ,1300 , 1500),
 (16   ,2924  ,'2014-01-07 17:11:00'    , 5    ,1300 ,   50),
 (17   ,2924  ,'2014-01-07 19:31:38'    , 5    ,1030 ,    0),
 (18   ,2924  ,'2014-01-07 21:00:53'    , 5    ,1300 ,  200),
 (19   ,2924  ,'2014-01-07 21:59:17'    , 5    ,1300 ,  500),
 (20   ,2924  ,'2014-01-08 08:28:53'    , 5    ,1300 , 1000),
 (21   ,2924  ,'2014-01-08 08:56:33'    ,26    ,1300 ,  500),
 (22   ,2924  ,'2014-01-08 11:41:06'    ,26    ,1300 , 1000),
 (23   ,2924  ,'2014-01-08 11:41:41'    , 5    ,1300 , 1500);

 SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN
     ( SELECT plantno,my_key
            , MAX(date) max_date
         FROM my_table
        GROUP
           BY plantno
            , my_key
     ) y
    ON y.plantno = x.plantno
   AND y.my_key = x.my_key
   AND y.max_date = x.date
 ORDER
    BY plantno,my_key;
+----+-------+---------------------+---------+--------+----------+
| id | SCADA | Date                | PlantNo | my_key | my_value |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------+--------+----------+
| 14 |  2924 | 2014-01-04 18:23:11 |       4 |   1030 |        1 |
| 17 |  2924 | 2014-01-07 19:31:38 |       5 |   1030 |        0 |
| 23 |  2924 | 2014-01-08 11:41:41 |       5 |   1300 |     1500 |
| 12 |  2924 | 2014-01-04 12:00:07 |       5 |   2501 |        9 |
|  8 |  2924 | 2014-01-03 07:42:07 |       7 |   1300 |     2060 |
| 11 |  2924 | 2014-01-04 11:52:56 |      16 |   1031 |        0 |
|  7 |  2924 | 2014-01-03 07:42:06 |      25 |   1300 |     2060 |
| 22 |  2924 | 2014-01-08 11:41:06 |      26 |   1300 |     1000 |
+----+-------+---------------------+---------+--------+----------+
```

The hack equivalent to this query is as follows:

```
SELECT *
  FROM
     ( SELECT *
         FROM my_table
        ORDER
           BY Date DESC
     ) t
 GROUP
    BY plantno
     , my_key;
```